# Why can't I authenticate with my Youtube Brand Account (using Google JS API Client)?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, google-api-js-client, youtube-analytics-api

I am using the Google API JS Client to connect to my Youtube account to gather Analytics for my videos. The problem is some of them are on a Brand account that I own, and I keep getting an error when I try to connect to my Brand Account.

[image: Console Error when I select brand account from the accounts pop window]

Here is a [video showing the problem](https://youtu.be/lKVI7Xc4LCU).

Is there a different way to access the analytics data for the Brand Account that I own? I should note that I am not a Content Partner with Youtube, or anything like that.

[JS Code (from developers.google.com)](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/code_samples/javascript#retrieve_daily_channel_statistics)

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
<script>
function authenticate() {
return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
    .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly"})
    .then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
          function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
}
function loadClient() {
return gapi.client.load("https://youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v2")
    .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
          function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
}
// Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
function execute() {
return gapi.client.youtubeAnalytics.reports.query({
  "ids": "channel==MINE",
  "startDate": "2017-01-01",
  "endDate": "2017-12-31",
  "metrics": "views,estimatedMinutesWatched,averageViewDuration,averageViewPercentage,subscribersGained",
  "dimensions": "day",
  "sort": "day"
})
    .then(function(response) {
            // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
            console.log("Response", response);
          },
          function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
}
 gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
gapi.auth2.init({client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'});
 });
</script>
 <button onclick="authenticate().then(loadClient)">authorize and load</button>
 <button onclick="execute()">execute</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
As I understood Google brand profile doesn't contain information about user. It's not possible to use it for authentication. You need just change scope into `'profile email'`.
This was solution for me.